# Should a website use its own public API?

Tags: api

I am starting to write a webservice, and I've built with nodeJS and a RESTfulish approach.

From what I gather:

- The advantage is that you don't have to duplicate code.
- The disadvantages are that you:

  - will update the public API frequently, but should be solved with versioning
  - can't really make service specific caching and optimizations

What is considered best practice? Do sites such as Stack Exchange, Github, Twitter, etc use their own APIs for their clients?

Comment: Eating your own dogfood will also drive you to improve your public API

Comment: That is how Amazon does it.

Comment: To add to OlverS's point, see [Google Platforms Rant](https://plus.google.com/112678702228711889851/posts/eVeouesvaVX)

Comment: I think this might be impractical in most cases because an API usually exposes only a subset of the site's full functionality to the public. You might end up adding functionality to that API just because your own website needs it. This might even raise some security concerns if dealing with more sensitive data.

Answer (score 39):

You should absolutely use your own API. This concept is widely known as dogfooding and it has *many* benefits beyond avoiding code duplciation.

- Consistent behaviour between your site/product and what API consumers will write (ie. their expectations of your API)
- Another form of testing.
- You can and will find bugs in the API before your customers do, making their resolutions cost less.

Although I would argue against one of your points: you should *not* be updating the API frequently. Spend the time to architect and proof out an API that will stay around for a while. Fortunately, dogfooding in this way will enforce that. Where you would have just broken customer code before, you'll now be breaking your own code. When you *must*, yes versioning is a solution, but it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason it won't let me log in as the poster of the question, but it was me. I can't accept your answer, wish I could, it makes a lot of sense.

However, how can you not want to update your API? What about adding new features, removing unpopular ones, refactoring, etc?

Comment: Hey. This should be a comment on his answer - but I don't think you have enough rep to comment. Anyway, the point is that you shouldn't update the API *frequently*. And even then, adding new features is no problem - it can't break existing code. Why remove unpopular ones? Make them deprecated, and remove sometime in the future after people have had a long time to respond to the deprecation.

Comment: _Adding_ methods to an API is fine, _changing_ an existing API is bad because it will break any code that depends on the API.

Comment: @stanm87: Max and Bryan said it well. You should avoid changing the contract of your API (that is, the interface and the expected, working, behaviour). People will depend on that if they will use your API and if you change it, it will break their code.

Comment: thanks a lot for clarifying. @Max I indeed cannot comment on his answer